# Single word for "never fails"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, negation

Is there a single word for "never fails"?

Comment: How about "unfailing"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1- **[Inerrant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inerrant?show=0&t=1379222758)**

2- **[Unblemished](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unblemished)**

3- **[faultless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faultless)**

4- **[Indefectible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indefectible)**

5- **[Immaculate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immaculate)**

6- **[Impeccable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impeccable?show=0&t=1379222758)**

7- **[Flawless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flawless?show=0&t=1379222757)**

8- **[Infallible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infallible)**

Answer (score 10):

Yes:

> [*unnerring*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unerring): Committing no mistakes; consistently accurate.
>
> [*infallible*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/infallible) : 2. Incapable of failing; certain: an infallible antidote; an infallible rule.
>
> [*foolproof*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foolproof): 2. Effective; infallible: a foolproof scheme.
>
> [unfailing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unfailing) : 3. Incapable of error; infallible.

Comment: I'd forgotten unfailing, despite its being the most obvious, thanks @RoaringFish.

Answer (score 6):

I like:

1. surefire
2. reliable
3. rock
4. guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

Foolproof or bulletproof (bulletproof is more metaphorical, of course) can be used depending on the context.